# Filtering a layer with attribute value from another layer in Qgis 2.18

Tags: qgis, filter, expression

I am pretty new to Qgis and a real beginner when it comes to working with
expressions in Qgis. Maybe someone can help me with following problem:

[image: Example]

I have several Layers (like **Building + House**) and each of them have specific attributes values that i want to filter. So my idea was to get an extra layer **Test** with the attribute value that i want to filter on the other layers and put a filter expression to the attribute value **A** in table **category_1** of layer **Test**. Basically to avoid rewriting the filters for each layer all the time. But I dont know how to get it done.
I tried it with get_feature and attribute() but in my Qgis 2.18 there is no help how such expressions have to look like. That makes it really hard if u have no clue.
So how can I filter with the attribute value **A** in **category_1** of layer the **Test** in the layer **House** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is about *Select features using an Expression* [image] function, please try examples below:

**House**

```
"category_2" = attribute(get_feature('Test', 'ID', '1'), 'category_1')
```

**Building**

```
"category_3" = attribute(get_feature('Test', 'ID', '1'), 'category_1')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is rather a task for databases, the filtering across layers based on attributes. GIS' are used to filter across layers based on spatial data.

What you can do: Build a virtual layer (`layer -> add layer -> virtual layer`) with all your layers you want to filter and use the correct SQL-terms.

Comment: So it is not possible with an filter expression ? Rather than having any SQL knowledge I already fail to create a virtual layer. I always get errors for spefics layers while using the given import function. So I think this will lead to many more questions. But thx for the Idea.