# Style a feature in one layer based on an attribute in another layer in Print Composer Atlas

Tags: qgis, print-composer, expression, atlas, rule-based

I have two layers; one is the foreground and the other a background. Both layers have fields containing similar values (field values in the foreground layer (`mun_code`) is also present in the background layer's fields (`ADM3_PCODE`). For instance, both fields may contain the value `012802000`).

For the background layer, I am trying to use Rule-based styling to add a thicker border using the expression:

```
@mun_code = attribute( $currentfeature, 'ADM3_PCODE' )
```

but `@mun_code` returns `NULL` (most likely because `mun_code` as a field is only present in the foreground layer while the background layer contains the field `ADM3_PCODE`):

[image: Rule-based styling problem]

I already Generated an atlas choosing the foreground layer as the Coverage layer. My understanding is that `$currentfeature` (in the code above) is already automatically controlled by the Print Composer Atlas, so I am wondering why it returns `NULL`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: maybe some of this might help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/filtering-features-in-other-layers-of-qgis-atlas

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. I managed to fix it using one rule having the expression `"ADM3_PCODE"  =  attribute( @atlas_feature , 'mun_code')` for feature of interest and another rule "ELSE" for features of no interest on the background layer.

Comment: There are other filters for doing intersects, etc. within the atlas feature layers... very powerful!

Answer (score 2):

@ is for QGIS integrated reserved variables ... i think u meant "mun_code" (keeping the double quotes) to reference the attribute value ...
But your aim remains unclear to me : Did u build any relation between the two tables ? Relation based on attributes *(has any join been setup ?)* or based on geography ? If u want to test the content of an attribute located **in another table** you have to define a clear relation.

Comment: Thanks. I did a table join, and also used double quotes but no difference. I think the main problem is like in this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290844/filtering-a-layer-with-attribute-value-from-another-layer-in-qgis-2-18 but the answers did not do any difference neither.